# Continuous Random Variables & Expected Value

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification, expected-value

Here is a three part question involving continuous random variables and expected value that I have attempted:

**Part A:** Given the following function, calculate the value of $C > 0$.

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
                C\sin^{2}(x) & 0\leq x \leq \pi \\
                0 & (-\infty\leq x \leq 0] \cup [\pi\leq x \leq +\infty)  
\end{cases}$$

**Computation**:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}C\sin^{2}(x)dx=C\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{2}(x)dx= C\frac{\pi}{2} $$

$$C\frac{\pi}{2}=1 \implies C=\frac{2}{\pi}$$

---

**Part B:** Using the function and the C-value you calculated above, find $E(X)$.

**Computation**:

$$E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xf(x)dx$$

$$E(X)=\int_{0}^{\pi}x\frac{2}{\pi}\sin^{2}(x)dx=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}x\sin^{2}(x)dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

---

**Part C:** Calculate $E(\cos(X))$.

**Computation**:

$$E(g(x))=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(x)f(x)dx$$

$$E(\cos(X))=\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(x)\frac{2}{\pi}\sin^{2}(x)dx=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(x)\sin^{2}(x)dx = 0$$

---

*For each computation we should be integrating from $-∞$ to $+∞$. To save some time and space, I only integrated from $0$ to $π$ because the integrals will be equal to zero outside of that interval.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[X]$ should be $\pi/2$ since you plugged in $C$ to be $\pi/2$ instead of $2/\pi$. Rest of it seems correct.

Comment: Ah, yes. I will make that edit now.

Comment: What is the question?